# How to create Onyx material in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I am struggling to create onyx kind of material, if somebody can help me please

[image]

I have created following node graph:

[image]

i am getting such output :

Comment: Could you add the output image please? You can also add images directly to you question instead of posting links. Look for the small image icon at the top of the text editor.

Comment: The image of your nodes is too small, It's very hard to tell what you have going on. Please edit your question with an image that shows relevant information only, and in a readable manner.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not experienced with cycles but share some ideas on how to approach this. You could start with a Voronoi texture to get the cellular look:
[image]

Then add a color ramp with colors occuring in the image.

The cells in your image have different sizes this means whe need to mix two Voronoi textures which different scales. The borders of the cells are not as smooth as in the Voronoi texture here some noise could help.

[image]

the upper part of the nodes (including noise) could look like:
[image]
the lower part (overlay) something like this:

[image]

Combined by mix shader:
[image]

[image]

Comment: really good shader. It seems that the fresnel is useless on a flat surface, could be a simple mix.

Comment: @bithur thanks. Yes I realized that after posting the images, manual mixing gives more control.

Comment: You could add a small amount of noise to the vector input of the voroni texture make the cell shape less circular

Comment: BAD!!! dud pasteall link! Destroy!!!!!